# Force CRL refresh in OSX & Vista

Tags: https, ssl-certificate

I've installed a wildcard SSL certificate for two subdomains that I'm working on for an organization. This is the first time I've worked with wildcard certificates, and I missed installing the intermediate certificate when I first set this up, which resulted in certificate revocation messages when I first tried to load them. I've reloaded the certificates correctly, and both subdomains check out now using http://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html.

The sites appear to load fine everywhere except on the two machines (Mac Laptop & Vista Desktop) that I use to develop on, where they're still showing revoked. I've tried to refresh my local CRLs using the following commands:

certutil -setreg chain\ChainCacheResyncFiletime @now (Vista)

and

crlrefresh r p (mac)

I've restarted both computers and cleared browser caches but am still not able to access. How can I get my local machines to forget that the certificate was initially revoked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to ask the organization I'm working with to regenerate the certificate. I installed that one and everything's good to go now.